# Propel ORM with Two FK Columns To Same Foreign Table

Tags: mysql, propel

I have a table that contains two foreign keys that map back to a membership table. They are named "from_member" and "to_member."

I am trying to get the Member object that represents this membership table by doing something like:

```
$feedbackQuery = FeedbackQuery::create()->findOne();
$fromMember = $feedbackQuery->getFromMember();
```

So that I can go like this:

```
$firstName = $fromMember->getFirstName();
```

The only problem is you can't do that, evidently Propel requires you to call $fedbackQuery->getMember()and who knows what that's going to return in this case.

Is there any easy way to accomplish getting the member data like this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming that you are using from_member_id and to_member_id as your foreign keys, you should have two methods at your disposal. getMemberRelatedByToMemberId() and getMemberRelatedByFromMemberId().

To find your from_member object and to use it.

```
$fromMember = $feedbackQuery->getMemberRelatedByToMemberId(); 
$firstname = $fromMember->getFirstName();
```

Comment: If you switch to an auto-completing IDE, such as Eclipse or Netbeans, these methods will present themselves automatically - I find it invaluable for Propel development.